# How to darken a gradient in sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I downloaded a Bootstrap Theme and there they use [Sass darken](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html), to make the button more *obscure* on hover. I managed to use the [instagram gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751375/instagram-new-logo-css-background) as it's background, though since the darken function requires a base color I was wondering, how could I achieve the same effect?

(I guess I could just us opacity on hover instead for all of the social buttons but I was hoping to address this just for the sake of science)

Comment: You can darken every color in gradient on hover.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, darken(#667DB6, 5), darken(#0082C8, 5))
```